# Two foreign keys in a model referencing the same table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

It seems I have a problem if I have two properties in a model that reference another table as foreign keys. The engine assigns unexpectedly weird column names to them and as a result I get an SQL error. Let me show my source code.

```
create table Units
(
    UnitID int identity 
        constraint PK_Units primary key,
    AspNetUserID nvarchar(128) not null 
        constraint FK_Units_AspNetUserId references AspNetUsers(Id),
    [Name] nvarchar(255) not null
);

create unique index UIX_Units_AspNetUserID_Name 
    on Units(AspNetUserID, [Name]);

create table Products
(
    ProductID int identity 
        constraint PK_Products primary key,
    BusinessID int not null 
        constraint FK_Products_BusinessID references Businesses(BusinessID),
    SKU nvarchar(31) null,
    [Name] nvarchar(255) not null,
    AdditionalName nvarchar(255) null,
    UnitID int not null 
        constraint FK_Products_UnitID references Units(UnitID),
    UnitPrice decimal(12, 2) not null,
    TareUnitID int null 
        constraint FK_Products_TareUnitID references Units(UnitID),
    UnitsInTare decimal(12, 2) null,
    DefTaxRateID int null 
        constraint FK_Products_DefTaxRateID references TaxRates(TaxRateID)
);

create unique index UIX_Products_BusinessID_SKU_Name 
    on Products(BusinessID, SKU, [Name]);
```

The models generated by the VS engine. As you can see, the `Products` table references the `Units` table twice (`UnitID` and `TareunitID`).

```
public partial class Product
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Product()
    {
        this.InvoiceItems = new HashSet<InvoiceItem>();
    }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int BusinessID { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalName { get; set; }
    public int UnitID { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TareUnitID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> UnitsInTare { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DefTaxRateID { get; set; }

    public virtual Business Business { get; set; }
    public virtual TaxRate TaxRate { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit Unit1 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the following partial classes.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UnitMetadata))]
public partial class Unit : BasePartialModelClass { }

[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetadata))]
public partial class Product : BasePartialModelClass { }
```

And finally, I have the following metadata classes.

```
public class UnitMetadata
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UnitID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    [StringLength(128, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustBeMax128Characters")]
    public string AspNetUserID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustBeMax255Characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products1 { get; set; }
}

public class ProductMetadata
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    public int BusinessID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(31, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustBeMax31Characters")]
    [Display(Name = "UID", ResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
    public string SKU { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustBeMax255Characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustBeMax255Characters")]
    [Display(Name = "AdditionalName", ResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
    public string AdditionalName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Unit")]
    public int UnitID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired")]
    [Display(Name = "UnitPrice", ResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Unit1")]
    public Nullable<int> TareUnitID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UnitsInTare", ResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
    public Nullable<decimal> UnitsInTare { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TaxRate")]
    [Display(Name = "DefTaxRateID", ResourceType = typeof(GlobalRes))]
    public Nullable<int> DefTaxRateID { get; set; }

    public virtual Business Business { get; set; }

    public virtual TaxRate TaxRate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UnitID")]
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TareUnitID")]
    public virtual Unit Unit1 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create a view out of Product I get an error.

It seems, it's something wrong with the generated SQL query. So, I used XEvents and had a look at the query.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Extent1].[BusinessID] AS [BusinessID], 
    [Extent1].[SKU] AS [SKU], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[AdditionalName] AS [AdditionalName], 
    [Extent1].[UnitID] AS [UnitID], 
    [Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
    [Extent1].[TareUnitID] AS [TareUnitID], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsInTare] AS [UnitsInTare], 
    [Extent1].[DefTaxRateID] AS [DefTaxRateID], 
    [Extent1].[Unit_UnitID] AS [Unit_UnitID], 
    [Extent1].[Unit_UnitID1] AS [Unit_UnitID1]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Name] ASC)
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

The question is, how to make it work properly? Why does it put those columns to the query? Please notice, the

```
TareUnitID int null 
     constraint FK_Products_TareUnitID references Units(UnitID),
```

works normally, no problem. I only have problems with `Unit` which is referenced twice.

Comment: "generated by the VS engine" - can you explain exactly what that is and what EF engine you're using?

Comment: Just selected "Update model from database" on the model graph. Using VS 2017.